# Deleting certain files in powershell script

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, foreach, try-catch

I have a powershell script that goes through a directory and deletes files that are older than 18 months.  Most of the files follow the following naming convention:

`20140628`

However, some of the files do not.  I am trying to make the script ignore these files and just delete the files that follow the naming convention.  For some reason, though, the script below is doing the exact opposite of that and deleting the files that do not follow the naming convention and leaving the ones that do.  How would I modify the script to fit my needs? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$targetdirectory = "\\DPR320-W12-1600\PRTG"
$CleanupList = Get-ChildItem $targetdirectory\test
$Threshold = (get-date).AddMonths(-18)
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

foreach ($DirName in $CleanupList)
{
try {
  [datetime]::ParseExact($DirName.BaseName, 'yyyyMMdd', $culture)
  Remove-Item $DirName.FullName -Force -Recurse
} 

catch {

  continue
}

}
```

Comment: Where's the 'cleanup' process?

Answer (score 0):

```
$targetDirectory = "\\DPR320-W12-1600\PRTG"
$cleanupList = Get-ChildItem $(Join-Path $targetdirectory "test")
$threshold = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-18)
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

foreach ($dirName in $cleanupList) {
    try {
        $dateFromName = [datetime]::ParseExact($dirName.BaseName, "yyyyMMdd", $culture)

        if($dateFromName -le $threshold) {
            Remove-Item $dirName.FullName -Force -Recurse
        }
    } catch {
        Continue
    }
}
```

If parsing as a date fails, an error will be thrown and file will not be deleted.

I'm not even sure `Continue` is needed here, but you cannot remove the `catch` block.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my edited script.  I posted the incorrect one at first.  It now has the deletion line. However, it deletes all files with dates.  How would I make it just delete the files that older than 18 months?

Comment: What date should be used for comparison ? The one that is parsed from the name ? File modification ? File creation ?

Comment: Yes. It should take in the file/directory name and compare it against todays date which is set in one of the variables at the top of the script.